# Some questions are marked as duplicate to other questions which haven't any answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

I remember seeing many questions marked as duplicate by other Stack Overflow users, while the other question hadn't been answered. The two questions were similar however none of them actually had an answer.

This way the OP did not get any answer in his question. Wouldn't it be better if questions are marked as duplicate to other questions, only if the latter actually have an answer?

Comment: I thought you could only do that anyway? Have you an example?

Comment: This already exists - posts can't be closed as a duplicate if it has no accepted/upvoted answer. An exemption is made for posts by the *same user* which can be closed as a duplicate. On metas that rule doesn't apply anyway. The only other exemption is that moderators can dupe close regardless of it being the same user or meeting the other criteria (very very rare).

Comment: @Bugs unfortunatelly not. There has been a while since I saw such an example.

Comment: `There has been a while since I saw such an example.`  that's because the problem has already been solved, as Jon explains above. :)

Comment: @JonClements, I'd say that was the answer to this question.

Comment: @Bugs fairly sure there's a link somewhere I can reference but I'm on mobile at the mo'. So just tapped it out for the OP for now. Hopefully the community can dig it up before at a desk later :-)

Comment: @JonClements, could you mean [Changes to “close as duplicate” (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux)?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the answer was deleted *after* the closing was done - if the askers are not the same user. If you can find an example, we can confirm that

Comment: @Bugs that's the one - thanks:  *There are some exceptions to the requirement that the original have answers. First, mods can close as dupe of anything, to handle any special cases. Second, you can always close as dupe if it's from the same user, to cover the case of problem users who post the same thing multiple times. Last but not least, this check is disabled on meta.*  - so yes - unless there's a specific post in question...

Comment: Thank you all. Unfortunatelly, I can't remember what the question I had seen was about. I'm happy that this issue has been resolved, as it benefits the huge community of SO.

Comment: Are you talking about unanswered questions asked by the same user being marked as duplicates of each other? (e.g I ask "What is the fastest way to concatenate two strings", then I ask "How do I avoid performance problems when concatenating strings", then the latter is marked as a dupe of the former while the former isn't answered)

Comment: @dorukayhan no, I am talking about situations like this: eg. You ask "how to create a string in Java" and you get any answer. I have the same question, so after googling I get your question but I see no answer, so I ask again. Then, other people mark my answer dupe to your question, although your question hasn't any answer.